# Magento Upgrade 2.2.10 to 2.3.3 Getting Integrity constraint violation php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database, magento2.3.3

I have upgraded from `Magento2.2.10` to `Magento2.3.3`

after running

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I got this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (db_amit.#sql-14b6_7ed, CONSTRAINT
>   CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID FOREIGN KEY (entity_id)
>   REFERENCES catalog_product_entity (entity_id) ON DELETE CASCADE),
>   query was: ALTER TABLE catalog_product_entity_decimal MODIFY COLUMN
>   value decimal(20, 6)NULL COMMENT "Value", ADD CONSTRAINT
>   CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID FOREIGN KEY (attribute_id)
>   REFERENCES eav_attribute (attribute_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, ADD
>   CONSTRAINT CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID FOREIGN KEY
>   (entity_id) REFERENCES catalog_product_entity (entity_id) ON DELETE
>   CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT
>   CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DECIMAL_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID FOREIGN KEY
>   (store_id) REFERENCES store (store_id) ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: try this link :- https://magescale.com/2015-2/

Answer (score 0):

You should check in the table **catalog_product_entity_decimal**, are there any col which has **entity_id** = no exist in table **catalog_product_entity**?

Please run this query:

```
select * from catalog_product_entity_decimal where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity)
```